# How can I turn an anonymous object into key/value pairs or HTML attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, anonymous-types, html

In my MVC application, I have a helper class designed to render a group of related buttons. I'm trying to pass in the buttons' HTML attributes as an anonymous object:

```
new { @class="myClass1 myClass2" }
```

The helper emits HTML as an `MvcHtmlString`, which I'm currently building like this:

```
        foreach (var b in _buttons)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<button type='submit' name='{0}' {1}>{2}</button>",
                b.Value,
                b.HtmlAttributes,
                b.Text);
        }
```

My problem is that the above code produces invalid HTML:

```
<button type='submit' name='Foo' { class = myClass1 myClass2 }>Bar</button>
```

Unfortunately, since it's passed to the helper as an `object`, I don't have type information to work with. I could `ToString` the object and parse the result, but that seems pretty silly. How can I programmatically convert an anonymous object into `key="value"` style HTML attributes? Is there an existing utility for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the `TagBuilder` class, which builds HTML tags for you.

You can then write

```
builder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(HtmlAttributes));
```

Comment: I didn't use TagBuilder in my final version, but thanks for letting me know it exists. +1.

Comment: Update: This isn't the method I used, but that's because my case was somewhat unique. `TagBuilder` is best practice, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Any equivalent for ASP.NET web forms?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo: You can reference `System.Web.Mvc.dll` from a WebForms project and use this class.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, there's a static method for this on the `HtmlHelper` class:

```
HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(b.HtmlAttributes)
```

This solved my issue:

```
    foreach (var b in _buttons)
    {
        var dict = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(b.HtmlAttributes);

        var attr = dict.Keys.Zip(
            dict.Values, 
            (k, v) => string.Format("{0}='{1}'", k, v));

        sb.AppendFormat("<button type='submit' name='{0}' {1}>{2}</button>",
            b.Value,
            string.Join(" ", attr),
            b.Text);
    }
```

I also tried it with a TagBuilder and got about the same amount of code.

---

**Edit:** As Slaks pointed out, doing it this way is a potential XSS vulnerability. There was no risk in my specific use case, but TagBuilder seems like the best practice.

Comment: However, your version is an XSS vulnerability.  Use `TagBuilder`; don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Slaks - I have control over the values going into the HTML, and they're a limited set of values that don't come from user input. Point taken, though.

Comment: I found this answer useful when building complex components where you don't the whole control of your HTML.